# Cannot create dijits via dojo.NodeList.instantiate

Tags: dojo

I am trying to get dijits to render using the `dojo.NodeList.instantiate` method, which takes existing HTML elements and turns them into dijits when the DOM has loaded.

The API reference for the `instantiate` method can be found [here](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3/dojo.NodeList.instantiate).

The following example, which calls the `instantiate` method in the `dojo.addOnLoad` method, should create a `BorderContainer` with two `ContentPane` instances, but the DIVs remain as they start out, and do not become dijits:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Dijit Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "dojoroot/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";
        @import "dojoroot/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dojoroot/dojo/dojo.js"
        djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");

        dojo.addOnLoad(
            function() {
                dojo.query("#divOuter").instantiate(
                    dijit.layout.BorderContainer, {
                        design  :   'sidebar',
                        gutters :   false
                    }
                );

                dojo.query("#divMiddle").instantiate(
                    dijit.layout.ContentPane, {
                        region  :   'center'
                    }
                );

                dojo.query("#divRight").instantiate(
                    dijit.layout.ContentPane, {
                        region      :   'right',
                        splitter    :   true
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divOuter" style="width:400px;height:300px">
        <div id="divMiddle">Middle box</div>
        <div id="divRight">Right box</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried the above code in both Firefox 3.5 and Internet Explorer 7 and both fail to render the dijits. If I specify a standard HTML attribute in a property object (such as the `style` attribute), this style change appears correctly, indicating that the object is being read:

```
// The red border appears when using this example
dojo.query("#divRight").instantiate(
    dijit.layout.ContentPane, {
        region      :   'right',
        splitter    :   true,
        style       :   'border:1px solid red'
    }
);
```

The following HTML (using `dojoType` and other property attributes) works fine - the BorderContainer and ContentPanes appear correctly in both browsers:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="sidebar" gutters="false"
        style="width:400px;height:300px">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center">Middle box</div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="right" splitter="true" 
        style="width:200px;">Right box</div>
</div>
```

Please can anyone tell me why the `instantiate` example does not work?

I have done a lot of searching, but cannot seem to find anyone else with this issue, which may mean that I'm not using the `instantiate` method correctly!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call startup on those dijits after they are instantiated.  `dojo.query.instantiate` doesn't do it for you since it just creates the objects.

At the bottom of your onLoad function, add these:

```
 dijit.byId('divOuter').startup();
 dijit.byId('divMiddle').startup();
 dijit.byId('divRight').startup();
```